# Magento 2.3.5: Sorting Products with text type attribute with Flat Catalog Product Function on causes wrong sorting

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, category-products, product-sorting

I created a text type attribute called display_order with the following settings.

- Catalog Input Type for Store Owner - Text Field
- Used for Sorting in Product Listing - Yes

The display_order text for each product is 1, 2, 3, 4 ... and when the products display on the category page they're ordered as such.

However when I set Flat Catalog Product to "Yes" the display order gets changed to something else as shown in this [article](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/flat-catalog-product-function-problem-in-sorting-product/)

Is there any way of fixing this, so with Flat Catalog Product set to "Yes" the display order doesn't change?

Comment: Good to see that your issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this attribute will not visible on frontend, you can change it's type to any other type.

The solution to this issue is you need to create attribute with type **"Price"** instead of **"Text Field"**. You cannot change attribute type after creating attribute, so in order to do that follow this instruction

- Delete old attirbute, i.e, `display_order`
- Create new one with same attribute code `display_order`
- While creating attribute set attribute type `Price`, this will work perfectly with numbers

Hope this will resolve the issue

**#EDIT**
To hide `$` sign from product edit page include custom css file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/custom_product_edit.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/custom_product_edit.js` you can hide `$` sign, like this:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            jQuery('input[name=product\\[display_order\\]]').next("label").children("span").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems to work, but is there any way of hiding the $ sign that shows up against the attribute on the backend product page? I found that this hides it but don't know where to put in in CSS.  [data-index|=display_order] span {
  display: none;

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thanks, so I created a module and created the folders and files along with the etc/module.xml and registration.php and added this css into the product_edit_custom.css - [data-index|=display_order] .admin__control-addon label span {
  display: none;
}

It doesn't seem to hide the $

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try this solution, hope this will help

Comment: When I check the page source the js file shows, but when I open it, it gives this error.

Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Vendor_DisplayOrder/js/custom_product_edit.js'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource#0000000079d1a7a4000000000cccda37#) called at [pub/static.php:13]
</pre>

Comment: please share your xml code and js file location in your question

Comment: xml file location
app/code/Vendor/DisplayOrder/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml

js file location
app/code/Vendor/DisplayOrder/view/web/js/custom_product_edit.js

Comment: XML code 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_DisplayOrder::js/custom_product_edit.js"/>
    </head>
</page>

js file location
app/code/Vendor/DisplayOrder/view/web/js/custom_product_edit.js

Comment: Oh. my bad.. js file location will be this: `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/custom_product_edit.js` I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!